# Skeletal animation blending with Assimp

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, assimp, inverse-kinematics

I'm making a game and I've just got basic animation working (hooray!) and I'm now looking to improve upon it by incorporating animation blending. However, I'm having trouble finding any meshes or tutorials. Furthermore, I'm not entirely sure if skeletal animation is the way forward or whether Inverse Kinematics would be a better idea (maybe a mix?). Any advice?